# synchronizing access to HashMap from outside

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

I have a private `HashMap` and I am using `Collections.synchronizedMap()` on it. The API says that it is not really "thread-safe" when the map is iterated. I usually use `Map.entrySet()` to iterate maps so I think the map needs a manual synchronization block like the API shows. But from outside I can't synchronize on the map reference because it is private.... I'm wondering if I should provide a getter to the actual map reference (maybe this is not good OOP design), or return a deep copy of the map? (maybe this is slow). I don't know what the best way to go with this kind of situation is. Can somebody give some idea or tell me what is the most typical way to face this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) if you really need concurrent access to a HashMap. This is part of the util.concurrent package with Java 5+. It performs much better in a multi-threaded environment than the Synchronized wrappers do.

If you have no control over how the map is created (perhaps it is in a third party library), then you will need to synchronize access when you iterate over it. See the JavaDocs for [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) for more info. Here is the sample code included in the API docs.

```
  Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
      ...
  Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
      ...
  synchronized (m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
      Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

Comment: I thinked about ConcurrentHashMap, but really i need that to work with a few threads that just ocasionally access the map at the same time?

Comment: @Wyvern666 I use ConcurrentHashMap over Collections.synchronizedMap in every case where multiple threads may access the map. I do not see a reason not to.

Comment: The synchronization is donde on the map reference, but the reference is private. So how to synchronize it from another class when iterating?